# How to minimize the Absolute Difference loss in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I have tried to reproduce Flownet 1.0 in tensorflow for days.the reconstruction is not hard， but the Absolute Difference loss displayed on tensorboard seems fell into loop.
[image]

The main code that you may wanna know are shown below.

```
#iamges1_shape = iamges2_shape = [batch, 461, 589, 6]
def inference(iamges1, images2, flownet_groud_truth):
    with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
        iamges1 = iamges1 * 0.00392156862745
        images2 = images2 * 0.00392156862745
        inputs = tf.concat([iamges1, images2], axis = 3)
        conv1 = tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(inputs, 64, 5, [2, 2] )
        conv2 = tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(conv1, 128, 5, stride=[ 2, 2] )

        blablabla....

        flowloss = tf.losses.absolute_difference(regroud_truth, predict_flow )    
        final_flow = 20*final_flow 

        return final_flow, flowloss

lr = tf.train.exponential_decay(0.0001,
                                global_step,
                                10000,
                                0.99,
                                staircase=True)
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=lr)
train_op = opt.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(
        allow_soft_placement=True,
        log_device_placement=False))
sumwriter = tf.summary.FileWriter('/tmp/flow', graph=sess.graph)

threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess )
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for step in range(100000):
    gdt = flowIO.next_GroudTruthFlow_batch(gd_truth_name_list, 4)
    _ , total_loss, summary = sess.run([train_op, loss, merged ], feed_dict={gd_truth:gdt })
    print('---------', 'step %d' % step)
    print(' loss is %f ' % total_loss )
    if step % 200 == 0:
        sumwriter.add_summary(summary, step)
```

I also tried other learning_rate,like 0.1,0.001,etc,even the Optimizer.However,the loop is still here，just different shape.

Considering that too many urgly code may hurt your mood，I do not post all of it.If more information could help,you will get it.

Any suggestion will be appreciate. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please provide full code (right now there is no logic connecting loss variable with inference function; argument to loss does not match argument passed to inference; no way to see how you create predictions etc.); also please provide some sample input signals. Do you use mini-batch learning? If so - with how big batches?

Comment: I hava pushed full code to https://github.com/chuchienshu/flownetS. If you have time, I hope you can have a look. Thanks in advance! @lejlot